# Fast subsetting of a matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, ref

I face the following problem: I need many subsets of a big matrix. Actually I just need views as input for another function f(), so I don't need to change the values.  However it seems, that R is terribly slow for this task, or I'm doing something wrong (which seems more likely). The toy example illustrates how much time it takes just to select the columns, and then use them in another function (in this toy example the primitive function sum()). As 'benchmark' I also test the calculation time against summing up the whole matrix, which is surprisingly faster. I also experimented with the package ref, however could not achieve any performance gain. **So the key question is how to subset the matrix without copying it?** I appreciate any help, Thanks!

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ref)

m0 <- matrix(rnorm(10^6), 10^3, 10^3)
r0 <- refdata(m0)
microbenchmark(m0[, 1:900], sum(m0[, 1:900]), sum(r0[,1:900]), sum(m0))
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
>       m0[, 1:900] 10.087403 12.350751 16.697078 18.307475 19.054157
>  sum(m0[, 1:900]) 11.067583 13.341860 17.286514 19.123748 19.990661
>  sum(r0[, 1:900]) 11.066164 13.194244 16.869551 19.204434 20.004034
>           sum(m0)  1.015247  1.040574  1.059872  1.049513  1.067142
>        max neval
>  58.238217   100
>  25.664729   100
>  23.505308   100
>   1.233617   100
> ```

The benchmark task of summing the whole matrix takes 1.059872 milliseconds and is about 16 times faster than the other functions.

Comment: I get an error when I try your example: `Error in r0[, 1:900] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: `library('ref')` fixes it

Comment: OK so what's the criteria here for a solution? Does it just have to be faster than what you're doing now or would it have to be faster than summing up the whole matrix?

Comment: Using `Rcpp` or `compiler` would probably give you the performance gains you need

Comment: @Hack-R The compiler is often not that useful.

Comment: @F.Privé Idk, it still gave a 50% performance boost, but of course your approaches were definitely better. Compiler did even better in this very similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806693/make-cumulative-sum-faster Well, anyway compiler is *easier* that Rcpp but nothing is better than the first solution you put (`sum(colSums(m0)[1:900])`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that the subsetting is allocating another matrix, which takes times.

You have two solutions:

If the time taken with `sum` on the whole matrix is okay with you, you could use `colSums` on the whole matrix and subset the result:

```
sum(colSums(m0)[1:900])
```

Or you could use Rcpp to compute the `sum` with subsetting without copying the matrix.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sumSub(const NumericMatrix& x,
              const IntegerVector& colInd) {

  double sum = 0;

  for (IntegerVector::const_iterator it = colInd.begin(); it != colInd.end(); ++it) {
    int j = *it - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.nrow(); i++) {
      sum += x(i, j);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

    microbenchmark(m0[, 1:900], sum(m0[, 1:900]), sum(r0[,1:900]), sum(m0),
                   sum(colSums(m0)[1:900]),
                   sumSub(m0, 1:900))
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
             m0[, 1:900] 4.831616 5.447749 5.641096 5.675774 5.861052  6.418266   100
        sum(m0[, 1:900]) 6.103985 6.475921 7.052001 6.723035 6.999226 37.085345   100
        sum(r0[, 1:900]) 6.224850 6.449210 6.728681 6.705366 6.943689  7.565842   100
                 sum(m0) 1.110073 1.145906 1.175224 1.168696 1.197889  1.269589   100
 sum(colSums(m0)[1:900]) 1.113834 1.141411 1.178913 1.168312 1.201827  1.408785   100
       sumSub(m0, 1:900) 1.337188 1.368383 1.404744 1.390846 1.415434  2.459361   100
```

You could use [unrolling optimization](https://privefl.github.io/blog/Tip-Optimize-your-Rcpp-loops/) to further optimize the Rcpp version.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. +1. I think my comment calling it out before we implemented it deserves a +1 too tho ;) Really though, if `sum(colSums(m0)[1:900])` does that well we don't even need the more cumbersome `Rcpp`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I think you are abslutely right. The main issue is the allocation of memory for the copy of the matrix. Is it possible to do this in R without copying the matrix? I need the matrix subset as input for another selfwritten function, the sum() function just deals as example here.

Comment: Basically, I make all my functions so that they can opper on a subset of a matrix. If you don't want to make a copy, you'll need only functions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `compiler` I wrote a function that gets the result about 2x as fast as your other methods (8x that of `sum(m0)` instead of 16x):

```
require(compiler)

compiler_sum <- cmpfun({function(x) {
     tmp <- 0
     for (i in 1:900)
         tmp <- tmp+sum(x[,i])
     tmp
}})

microbenchmark( 
               sum(m0),
               compiler_sum(m0)
               )
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>              expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq       max
>           sum(m0) 1.016532 1.056030 1.107263 1.084503 1.11173  1.634391
>  compiler_sum(m0) 7.655251 7.854135 8.000521 8.021107 8.29850 16.760058
>  neval
>    100
>    100
> ```